# Unmount nginx server from port 8081

Tags: docker, nginx, server

I would like to know how to unmount nginx server that appears on my port 8081.

I used this command:

`docker run -d --name server -p 8081:80 nginx`

However, I already stopped and removed nginx server with docker and deleted the image, but I still have port 81 busy with the server.

[image]

Comment: Run `docker ps`

Comment: I have no images.

Comment: Why do you three times say port 81 and two times port 8081?

Comment: @HansKilian, you mean the fact that docker images and its network stack are host independent?

Comment: I'm just confused about which port you use. The container uses port 80 inside and you map it to something on the outside. Your command says that you've mapped it to 8081 but the title of your post says 81.

Comment: Then, I have changed it, but I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't have any docker container running you might have nginx installed on your system. Use one of the proposed ways [here](https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/) to identify the process running on 8081. You can then decide further moves like killing the processes pid.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre, I did it but there's no process listening... see below

Answer (score 0):

I did it and apparently I don't have any process listening on port 8081, by default.

[image]

Comment: you are checking for port 80 and port 81 respectively, not 8081.
Try with `sudo lsof -i :8081`